# If I change one button with CSS, the other is also changed

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem editing buttons using css.

In particular, I notice that if I modify the "Cancel changes" button, the "Delete article parts" button present in a different div is also modified.

Can someone help me?

```css
.button[type=submit],[type=button] {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: rgb(24, 73, 32);
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}
```

```html
<div class = "button">
   <button type = "submit" class = "full"> Save changes </button>
   <input type = "button" value = "Cancel changes"
   onclick = "clearResult (document.getElementById ('id'). value)" />
</div>

<div class = "buttons">
   <form action = "creaFrammento.html">
       <input type = "submit" value = "Add article part" />
   </form>

   <input type = "button" value = "Delete article parts" onclick = "confirmation ()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are targeting any element with this property `[type=button]`. This targets both "Cancel changes" button and the "Delete article parts".

To target one specific element, you can give it an `id` and select the element with that `id` in your CSS. As you can see below, I've given the "Delete article parts" an `id="delete-btn"` so the CSS targeting `#delete-btn` will only apply to it.

```css
.button[type=submit],[type=button] {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: rgb(24, 73, 32);
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#delete-btn:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}
```

```html
<div class = "button">
   <button type = "submit" class = "full"> Save changes </button>
   <input type = "button" value = "Cancel changes" id="delete-btn" onclick = "clearResult (document.getElementById ('id'). value)" />
</div>
<div class = "buttons">
   <form action = "creaFrammento.html">
       <input type = "submit" value = "Add article part" />
   </form>
   <input type = "button" value = "Delete article parts" onclick = "confirmation ()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use.button it is an element selector which means the CSS applies to whole buttons in your HTML page. To prevent that you can use a class selector or id selector. but when we using javaScript we need this id selector so the recommended thing is to use a class selector.